# How to get enum value by name in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, CameraMode) {
  DEFAULT,
  SMART,
  LIVENESS,
  DOCUMENT
};
```

I want to to something like

```
NSInt *mode = CameraMode.getValue("DEFAULT");
```

is it possible with Objective-C? I did something similar in Java like this:

```
CameraMode.valueOf("DEFAULT");
```

Comment: Not a full answer, but no, this isn't possible — unlike in Java, in C and Objective-C, `enum`s exist only at compile time, so there isn't even anything to look up at runtime by name. What is your use-case for looking up an enum value by name? The specifics will help determine suggestions for how to get an equivalent working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C doesn't support any extra functionality as part of enums, however nothing prevents you from writing your own helper functions:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, TDWState) {
    TDWStateDefault,
    TDWStateSmart,
    TDWStateLiveness,
    TDWStateUndefined
};

TDWState TDWStateFromString(NSString *string) {
    static const NSDictionary *states = @{
        @"DEFAULT": @(TDWStateDefault),
        @"SMART": @(TDWStateSmart),
        @"LIVENESS": @(TDWStateLiveness),
    };
    
    NSNumber *state = [states objectForKey:string];
    
    if (state) {
        return state.unsignedIntValue;
    } else {
        return TDWStateUndefined;
    }
};
```

Which then can be used like this:

```
TDWState state = TDWStateFromString(@"DEFAULT");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this  way I still need to map all values inside enum, but avoids to create if and elses, in my use case the enum came from a sdk import, so if it changes someday I need to add to enum.. the initial ideia was not do that but this solution for sure is better than I was using

Answer (score 0):

There is no language-support for something like this. After all, `typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, CameraMode) { … }` is basically just C with some fancy macros.

You have to implement such string to enum mappings yourself, unfortunately.